# how do I use geom_rect with discrete axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot rectangles but I have an x axis that's discrete values. How do I set the xmin and xmax values to start at a point between the discrete values?

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c("a","b","c"), y = c(1,2,3))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_rect(data = NULL, aes(
    xmin = "b", xmax = "c", ymin = 1.5, ymax = 2.5
  ), color="red", fill = NA)
```

[image]

This code plots a rectangle but I'd like to move it to the left a little. I kindof want to be able to set `xmin = "b"-0.5` and `xmax = "b"+0.5`, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_rect(data = df, aes(x = x, y=y), xmin = as.numeric(df$x[[2]]) - 0.5,
                                        xmax = as.numeric(df$x[[3]]) + 0.5,
                                        ymin = 0, ymax = 2)
```

This works, as if you call xmin and xmax etc outside of the `aes` call, you can use whatever you want. The factor levels are used in the plot to plot them out, so `as.numeric` will make sure you get the right one.

Comment: Thanks @jeremycg that answers my question and works! Thanks also for the tip that the factor levels are used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "b" + 0.5 makes sense, but you can do that only after "b" has been transformed to a number by a scale. This can be achieved by using [`xmax = stage(., after_scale = xmax + 0.5)`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) in the `aes`thetics mapping:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()+
  geom_rect(data = NULL, aes(
    xmin = stage("b", after_scale = xmin-0.5),
    xmax = stage("c", after_scale = xmax+0.5),
    ymin = 1.5,
    ymax = 2.5
  ), color="red", fill = NA)
```

(Note, that this works as well when your rectangles are defined by `data`.)

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>