# Add horizontal rectangle to categorical boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a boxplot with a horizontal rectangle behind the plots (or above with opacity). I am not sure how to do this with categorical x-axis values and force it to extend the entire width of the plot area. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642856/how-do-i-use-geom-rect-with-discrete-axis-values) was helpful, but I'm not sure how to extend the rectangle to the edges of the plot area.

Let's say we want to make a rectangle across the `diamonds` cuts between $3000 and $5000. I have attempted the code below, but it doesn't extend to the edge of the plot.

```
rectangle <- data.frame(x = c("Fair","Good","Very good", "Premium", "Ideal"), 
                    lower = rep(3000, 5),
                    upper = rep(5000, 5))
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price)) +
  geom_rect(data=rectangle, aes(xmin="Fair", xmax="Ideal", 
                                ymin=lower, ymax=upper), alpha=0.1)
```

Output

[image: boxplot with rectangle]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the rectangle to the panel edges you can set the limits as +/-Inf.

Also for a single rectangle like this (and not mapping any aesthetics) it may be worth just using `annotate`:

```
annotate("rect", xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=3000, ymax=5000, alpha=0.4)
```

but for completeness, you can still use a `geom_rect`call

```
geom_rect(aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=3000, ymax=5000), alpha=0.4)
```

You can move the rectangle behind the boxplots by changing the order of the geoms.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price)) +
    geom_blank() +
    annotate("rect", xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=3000, ymax=5000) +
    geom_boxplot()
```